# Update [epiphany] tag to [gnome-web], with [epiphany] as a synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The GNOME web browser is no longer called *Epiphany*, it is called [GNOME Web](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Web/), so the tag should be [gnome-web](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnome-web). This follows the example of `gnome-keyring` and so on.

*Epiphany* is still the "code name" so perhaps keep [epiphany](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epiphany) as a synonym?

Comment: The old name definitely needs to be kept as a synonym, and possibly should still be the primary name for a while. Tags names need to reflect actual usage (as long as there's no ambiguity), not necessarily official terminology.